# Django ListView - context not getting updated

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

## views.py

```
class PaginatorView(_LanguageMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'concepts'

    #some custom functions like _filter_by_first_letter   

    def get_queryset(self):
        # some logic here ...

        all_concepts = self._filter_by_letter(self.concepts, letters, startswith)
        #letters and startswith are obtained from the logic above

        print all_concepts
        return all_concepts

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PaginatorView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print context[self.context_object_name]
        context.update({
            'letters': [(l[0], self._letter_exists(context[self.context_object_name], l)) for l in self.all_letters],
            'letter': self.letter_index,
            'get_params': self.request.GET.urlencode(),
        })

        return context
```

The `print all_concepts` statement prints all my concepts correctly. So everything until here works just fine. Then, I return `all_concepts`.

Shouldn't at this point, `all_concepts` being added to the context, under the key specified by `context_object_name`? i.e., `context['concepts']` should be populated with `all_concepts`?

If so,the print statement inside `get_context_data` prints nothing. Which suggests me that the context was not updated.

When I previously used a DetailView, the `get_object` function was updating the context referenced by `context_object_name` correctly.(i.e. context[context_object_name] was populated with the object returned by `get_object`) Shouldn't `get_queryset` do the same for the ListView?

`_LanguageMixin` is also defined in **views.py**, but it is not so relevant for my problem. Just included it here for you to see

```
class _LanguageMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.langcode = kwargs.pop("langcode")
        self.language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=self.langcode)
        return super(_LanguageMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(_LanguageMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({"language": self.language,
                        "languages": Language.objects.values_list('code',
                                                                  flat=True)})
        return context
```

**[EDIT1]**

if instead I do save `all_concepts` i.e. `self.all_concepts=...` and then I use `self.all_concepts` instead of `context[self.contex_object_name]`, everything works fine.

**[EDIT2]**

I never instantiate the PaginatorView. It's only for extending purposes. Down here you can see how I extend it. `self.concepts` helps me to find `all_concepts` in the `get_queryset` of the parent class(PaginatorView)

```
class AlphabeticView(PaginatorView):
    template_name = "alphabetic_listings.html"
    model = Property

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.concepts = (
            self.model.objects.filter(
                name='prefLabel',
                language__code=self.langcode,
            )
            .extra(select={'name': 'value',
                           'id': 'concept_id'},
                   order_by=['name'])
            .values('id', 'name')
        )
        super(AlphabeticView, self).get_queryset()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print statement in `get_context_data` is printing empty because the variable `context_object_name` is empty. You should try `print context[self.context_object_name]`

EDIT: In response to your correction, try

```
print context[self.get_context_object_name(self.get_queryset())]
```

[get_context_object_name docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name)

EDIT 2: In response to your second edit, the reason its is printing 'None' is because you aren't returning from the `get_queryset` method of `AlphabeticView`. Change the last line in that method to

```
return super(AlphabeticView, self).get_queryset()
```

Comment: sorry, made an edit. When I print `context[self.context_object_name]` I get `None`

Comment: What do you get if you try `print self.context_object_name` or `print self.get_context_object_name(self.get_queryset())`?

Comment: and I want to make you sure that the `print all_concepts` right before the return `statement` prints me the correct data: a list of some dictionaries

Comment: sorry, `print self.context_object_name` prints `concepts`, while print `self.get_context_object_name(self.get_queryset())` prints first the list stored in `all_concepts`, then again `concepts`

Comment: The reason `all_concepts` is printed when you do `self.get_context_object_name(self.get_queryset())` is because it gets printed by the get_queryset method.  Also, I've updated my answer based on your second edit

Comment: Yes, I know why is printing so.... But, fortunately, you were right about the return statemnt. problem solved. Thanks captain!